# Optimize simple update on table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am running following query in a stored proceudre and it is taking 30 milliseconds to execute. Can anyone help me out to optimize this query:

Table Definition is:

```
Create Table Customer
(
   CustID int not null auto_increment,
   CustProdID int,
   TimeStamp DateTime,
   primary key(CustID)
);

Update Customer
Set TimeStamp = InputTimeStamp (stored procedure's Input)
Where CustID = InputCustID (stored procedure's Input)
and CustProdID = InputCustProdID; (stored procedure's Input);
```

Also besides primary index this table has simple index on custprodID column.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Manasi

Comment: To all your questions answer I have put debug statement of timestamp in my stored procedure before update starts and after completion of the Updation.
As i mentioned earlier these columns have index on it.

Answer (score 1):

How are you measuring the 30ms?  If by running the procedure once, the result will be swamped by overheads of running the test.  Put it in a loop and do it say 1000 times, then divide the result by 1000, what do you get then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's really much you could change here while maintaining the same functionality; it's a very basic query.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the time isn't spent in the stored procedure but in the code which calls it (plus the network overhead, etc).

Comment: this is the time when I call the procedure from mysql commandline

Comment: Run it a million times with the same code which your app will use. That will give you a good basis for an estimate how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 30 ms, is that cpu time or overall performance time?   Do  you know how many records are being updated (I am guessing a small number based on the example, but not sure).    Also, does the table have a trigger on it, so more work is being done than meets the eye...

I agree, this is a simple query, so not a lot to optimize it.   You might want to put a clustered index on the two fields, but I don't know if that is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and make use of a leftmost prefix index on (CustID, CustProdId).